What is an over the shoulder fanny pack called?
A fanny pack (a.k.a. a "bumbag") is a small pouch, usually sealed by a zipper, with an attached belt, meant to be worn around one's waist, an example of which appears below.

A fanny pack
There is a similar object that has come into style recently, that looks similar to a fanny pack, and is used by both men and women without contravening gender norms, which is intended to be worn over a single shoulder crossing the wearer's chest or back diagonally.
What is it called?

I think we all know what a fanny pack is. Do you have a picture of the thing you actually want a name for?

I've seen people wearing them in the neighborhood but don't know how to get an image of one since I don't know what it is called and I'm not quick on the draw with my own cell phone camera.

I suggest you delete the picture, since it will draw attention away from the actual answer you're looking for.

@Robusto I edited it to clarify that this was a fanny pack image and not what I'm trying to figure out the name for.

Is crossbody bag the term you're looking for?

Not really good enough, since the image is way bigger and brighter than your minuscule text. Not only that, but it's obviously a picture from the '80s—40 years ago. It's like you're asking what kind of hat the hipsters wear and then showing a picture of a stovepipe hat and saying "but not like this."

Also called a sling bag, if I understand the question.

"crossbody bag" and "sling bag" both sound right.

Also 'chest bag'.

@WeatherVane Those sound like answers!

Similar things have been known as "man bags" in the past. Some are also called travel pouches, but that's a very loose term.

I'm not sure this is what you mean, but I've seen it advertised as a "crossbody fanny pack" or a "shoulder sling bag".  Not all department stores in the US use the same terms, though.


This is the basic concept.

A crossbody bag. https://www.cnn.com/cnn-underscored/travel/best-crossbody-bags-purses

Traditionally, such a bag was called a haversack:

Haversack ...
A haversack, musette bag, or small pack is a bag with a single
shoulder strap. Although similar to a backpack, the single shoulder
strap differentiates this type from other backpacks. There are
exceptions to this general rule.

[Wikipedia, with caveats]
The term is (or was) admittedly used more widely:

Meaning of haversack in English
haversack [noun; count]   [old-fashioned]:
a bag, often made from strong, rough cloth, with one or two shoulder
straps


[Cambridge Dictionary]
They were often used in the army:

[VEMRA]
